# how to move a file in itemupdating

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

Like described in the title i'd like moving my file in itemupdating in place of itemupdated.
Like this the list is refreshed and file doesn't display anymore.

I use this that works and move correctly the file

```
properties.ListItem.File.MoveTo(pathTo + properties.ListItem.File.Name.ToLower(), true);
```

i get this exception at the end of the envent because the miva has moved so it doesn't update item.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: There is no file with URL 'http://mysp/test/best.jpg' in this Web.
```

Do you have a solution to perform this in SANDBOXsolution or maybe are there a way to refresh after itemupdated

thanks

Comment: is this exception because SharePoint wants to update your file but you moved it away already?